# How to implement mongoDB database with Dialogflow to create Chat Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dialogflow-es

Please help me!
I'm working on to create a chat application using dialogflow API. I have done all setup with dialogflow. I'm using Nodejs for backend and MongoDb database to store all chat data with username but I'm stuck to integrate my MongoDB database with dialogflow and store all chats. I'm using MLab to store my all data.

My code is here.

```
exports.pizzabot = function(req, res) {

console.log("pizza bot details here");

if (req.body.result.action === "a_fetch_user_details") {
    console.log("fetch user action fired");
    if (req.body.result.parameters["username"] != "") {
        return res.json({
            speech : "Fetched user details",
            displaytext : "welcome Bot!",
            followupEvent : {
                "data" : {
                    "pizzatype" : req.body.result.parameters["pizzatype"],
                    "pizzasize" : req.body.result.parameters["pizzasize"],
                    "username"  : req.body.result.parameters["username"],
                    "address"   : "New Delhi",
                    "phonenum"  : "1234567891",
                    "email"     : req.body.result.parameters["email"]
                },
                name : "e_fetch_user_details"
            },
            source : "from Dialogflow"
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck? all you have to do is trigger a function to save data into database before return statement.

Comment: How can I integrate MongoDb with Dialogflow? I want to find some details by username in chat. If username is correct then go to next step other wise It will show a message. But before doing this, I'm unable to integrate mongoDb with dialogflow.

Comment: you don't need to integrate mongoDb with DialogFlow, you will connect it in the backend code (webhook). in your example you are using nodejs. So just make a connection to the mongoDb, fire up a save_query, thats all.

Comment: see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imaA_s4jx9M&t=70s, it might be helpful.

Comment: I want to do like this :- I inserted some information with ‘username’ in my MongoDB and save it. Now during the ‘Chat’ using ‘Dialogflow-Chatbot’, I asked several questions and got answer, when Bot ask about your ‘username’ then I have to match username from MongoDB and go to the next step. But when user give the wrong username to the Bot, Bot will fire a message “Sorry, Username didn’t match”. So, If a user write a username on chat window I want to validate it against MongoDB credential.

Comment: you should make one more intent `wrong_username`, and trigger it using `events` from `webhook` if username does not match. set `contexts` for keeping user in flow.

Answer (score 0):

as sid8491 has said, you need to connect nodejs app with mongodb. You just need a function that connects to the database. Use mongoose if you need more functionality like validation and schema based approach. here is the code to connect to mongodb using mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongodb = require("../env");
mongoose.connect(mongodb.Mongo.url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => {
  console.log("MongoDB Connection successful");
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: Sir, Already done and I'm using MLab,  but I'm confused to connect mongoDB with Dialogflow. If it is done then How can I match username in chatbot by mongoDB.

Comment: You need query your database. Use findOne and pass the userName.